# Including module is confusing my classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

So I have a class called Item. And I'm including this Ebay Gem with it's own Item class. So when I call the Item class now, it confuses it with the Ebay's Item class. I know I can do something like this to point at my own Item class:

```
::Item
```

But I don't want to go back through all my code and change all Item to ::Item. It just doesn't feel right to do that and would be really annoying moving forward. I also have done something like

```
include Ebay::Types    
Item = ::Item
```

at the top of the class I included in the Ebay types but that just seems like a hack. Is there a cleaner way to do this? I would prefer my Item stays the same and I can call the Ebay variables like Ebay::Item.

Comment: Which gem are you referring to?

Comment: I'm using a Gem called EbayApi(https://rubygems.org/gems/ebayapi). I forked my own copy and I've been working on it since it's a bit outdated. But as you can see, it uses Item everywhere in the gem. So it would be a pain to go through and change it to something else.

Comment: If you include `Ebay::Types` I don't think there is any other way apart the one you wrote (I would be happy to get contradicted :-P )

Comment: yep, I agree with @mdesantis